# Postgresql dynamic queries

Tags: postgresql

```
DO
$$
    DECLARE 
    loginid varchar :='asdasdw';
    sql_stmt_part   TEXT;
    begin
     sql_stmt_part:=
      'select * from test.tablename where login_id=' loginid; 
     execute sql_stmt_part;

 end 
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Getting error  column 'aadasdw' does not exists......

Comment: `DO` cannot return results. Use a [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html).

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN - It is how to use external variable in the `execute` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned a `DO` will not return anything. To make the statement work though:

```
DO
$$
    DECLARE 
    loginid varchar :='asdasdw';
    sql_stmt_part   TEXT;
    begin
     execute  'select * from test.tablename where login_id='|| quote_literal(loginid); 
     

 end 
$$ language plpgsql;
```

The `login` variable needs to concatenated to the rest of the string and properly quoted(the `quote_literal`). This is just one way of doing it. Others can be found here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Thank you @Adrian Kiaver it's useful for me.